# Re-roll next value in pseudo-random sequence without changing any other values

Tags: random, probability, lfsr

I would like a pseudo-random number generator which generates an effectively-infinite (i.e. very large period) sequence that can be traversed in both directions but also allows re-rolling the value under the cursor.

For example, a starting view of the state (with square brackets indicating the cursor position) might be:

`... 1 7 3 [8] 4 1 6 ...`

After stepping the generator forward twice, the sequence `8 4` is generated and the view is:

`... 3 8 4 [1] 6 0 8 ...`

Then, the application chooses to re-roll the cursor value from `1`, and the generator produces `7`, resulting in the view:

`... 3 8 4 [7] 6 0 8 ...`

From this point, even if the cursor is moved backward, the newly generated value of `7` will remain in place of the original `1`. However, all other elements of the sequence will be unchanged:

`... 7 3 8 [4] 7 6 0 ...`

I considered using a reversible linear-feedback shift register (to allow stepping both left and right in the sequence) and writing to some set of bits in the center of the register to re-roll. However, to prevent re-rolling from affecting the rest of the sequence, only bits beyond the final tap can be re-rolled, and upon considering for a while, I realized it is probably not possible for a LFSR whose final tap is not all the way at the edge of the bit stream to be reversed.

Comment: Interesting question, however it's off topic here since it's not a specific programming question. I think cs.stackexchange.com is a more suitable audience.

Comment: You’ve told us what you think you want to do, but not why. What is the actual problem solved by what you’ve proposed? Why does your program throw a hissy fit about getting the 1, and then want a do-over of the 4 on top of that?